# UINavigationBar alpha removed

Tags: objective-c, xcode, uinavigationcontroller, uinavigationbar

I have the below set in my `viewDidLoad:`

```
self.navigationController.tabBarController.tabBar.tintColor = tintColor;
self.navigationController.tabBarController.tabBar.alpha = 0.7f;
```

I have set the alpha so the background image in my view bleeds through (giving the `UINavigationBar` a deeper color)

However when in iOS7 the code works fine when the app is started, but when I leave the view and then return the alpha setting has gone (and I am left only with the tint).

It works fine on the simulation on iOS6, but just not in iOS7, could this be a conflict of setting due to iOS7 new `UINavigationBar` features?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You might like to try something like this:

```
[[UITabBar appearance] setTintColor:[UIColor redColor]];
[[UITabBar appearance] setBarTintColor:[UIColor yellowColor]];
```

That should change the tint color of tabbar in iOS 7.

Also here is a link to a detail tutorial of how to munuplate the tabbar color also offers some source code.

https://www.captechconsulting.com/blog/steven-beyers/ios-7-tutorial-series-tint-color-and-easy-app-theming

Comment: I had just started to go down that route and it appears to have been what I am looking for, my initial problem was I was trying to create an iOS 6 (look and feel) app. I've taken the plunge and updated it to iOS 7 now